# "a priori pigeon-holing of learners" What is the meaning of this phrase?

Tags: meaning, phrases

...Teachers must certainly guard against "a priori pigeon-holing of learners" before we have even given learners a chance to perform...

Comment: I think you should be able to understand this just by looking up the words in a dictionary. Even Dictionary.com has solid entries for "a priori" and "pigeonhole (verb)." I'd start there.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what specific difficulties remain after you looked up *a priori* and *pigeonhole/pigeon-hole* in a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you guys, really. Do you think that I did not look up the phrase before writing the question here?

Comment: It sure looks that way if you don't give us any further information....  :-)  We could prattle on all day about what it says in the dictionary, but if you don't tell us what about the dictionary entry confuses you, it won't do anybody any good.

Comment: Should be closed, for the reasons cited in previous comments. If @phenry's answer answers the question then the question should be closed.  If it does not answer the question then please edit the question to provide a better description of what you want.

Comment: @Drew Where or what's phenry's Q?

Comment: @Araucaria: [phenry's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/202279/51214), not question.

Answer (score 1):

*A priori* has several related definitions; the one that is of interest here involves making a judgment or taking an action before performing the appropriate analytical steps to determine if the judgment or action is the best one. Think of it as a synonym for "premature."

To *pigeonhole* someone is to categorize them, probably unfairly or without due consideration.

Therefore, the sentence means that teachers should not prematurely categorize learners before they are given a chance to perform (which would then give the teachers more and better information to use when assessing the learners' progress).

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the two words involved here. A selection of definitions of “a priori” included “based on theory”, “inferred”, “presumptive”, and “theoretical”.  “Pigeonholed”  gave me “classified”, “dismissed”, “labeled”, and “sidelined”.

The sum of this research indicates that the sentence in question might read: *Teachers must certainly guard against sidelining of learners based on theory before we have given them a chance to perform*

*"There is a principle which is a bar against all information, which is proof against all arguments and which cannot fail to keep a man in everlasting ignorance—that principle is contempt prior to investigation." —Herbert Spencer*

Comment: I'm not exactly sure exactly to whom you've leveled the accusation of condescension, but the comments have merely pointed out that the question, as constituted at present, doesn't meet the requirements for this site. That's actually the opposite of insulting.